# How to remove HTML tags in a TableColumn

Tags: java, javafx

This is an example of what happens:

[image]

```
    previewTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("body"));
    subjectTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("subject"));
    dateTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("date"));

    tableView.getItems().setAll(model.getObservableDatas());
```

I need that the "Preview" column shows text without HTML tags, I was thinking to use Jsoup like this:

```
    public String htmlToText(String html) {
     String preview = null;
     if (html != null) {
        Document doc = Jsoup.parse(html);
        preview = doc.body().text();
     }
     return preview;
    }
```

The problem is that I need to get the String containing tags to invoke this method which comes from an HTMLEditor and is displayed on a WebView so I need to remove tags only in this column.
Is there any way to get the String and clean it from tags before putting it into the column?

**FIXED (maybe in a bad way)**

Datas class:

```
public class Datas implements Serializable {

private String subject;
private String date;
private String body;
private String bodyString;


 public Datas(String subject, String date, String body) {
    this.body = body; // I use this for HTMLEditor and WebView
    this.bodyString = htmlToText(body); // I use this for the TableColumn
    this.date = date;
 }
//getter and setter of everything
 public String getBodyString() {
    return bodyString;
 }

 public void setBodyString(String bodyString) {
    this.bodyString = bodyString;
 }
}
```

**In controller**

```
previewTableColumn.setCellValueFactory(new PropertyValueFactory<>("bodyString"));
```

**Bug that needs to be fixed:** if a client send data to a offline client, when the offline client gets online a duplicate value appear and the duplicate has no preview.

Comment: @kleopatra Actually I don't know which code to show, the problem is just the one shown in the image. I don't have lots of code about it, I just need to tell to TableColumn "ehy, you're receiving a String with HTML tags, remove those tags and show a clean text"

Comment: use a custom cellFactory ..

Comment: @kleopatra I'm gonna read something about custom cellFactory and post a solution if I fix, Thanks.
uitableview tag just a mistake. Sorry, I'm gonna edit.

Comment: yes, most probably that's not optimal ... typically you keep data mapping to  visual requirements as separated as possible. Repeating (and teeth-gritting ... arrrgggg): custom cell factory ...

Answer (score 4):

Something like;

```
private String getPreview(String _html) {
   String preview = null;
   if (_html != null) {
      Document doc = Jsoup.parse(_html);
      preview = doc.body().text();
   }
   return preview;
}
```

source: https://jsoup.org/cookbook/extracting-data/attributes-text-html

Comment: while the question is somehow vague .. I don't thing the unwrapping is the problem, it's how-to get that result to show up in a javafx TableView cell. But then, who except the OP knows :)

Comment: Yes, my problem is how to send to the TableColumn a String with no HTML tags and before using this method I need to get this string! I'm gonna post an example with TextArea, I have to do the same for TableColumn.

Comment: @MOTIVECODEX added an example with TextArea!

Comment: @NoProg unfortunately, I have no experience with javafx at all, so can't really guide you there sorry

Comment: As remark, I think you made a typo in your answer, there is no method `prase` ( `parse` is most probably the one you wanted to use).

Comment: @Pagbo thanks, typed it quick without ide :P

Comment: @NoProg so my answer solved it? Noticed your htmlToText method changed now to my version :P Maybe mark it as solved so others can use it too?

Comment: @MOTIVECODEX nope, your answer didn't solve it :) I just edited your versione for user that reads this!